# Angular 4 populate dropdown not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

In my component I am getting the response from REST but unable to populate the same in dropdown.

Component:

```
jobTitleList() {
    this.jobList = this.getJobList().then((result) => {
        this.jobList = result;
        console.log('result is : ', this.jobList );
    });
}
```

On console I am getting : result is :  `["Software Developer","Support Engineer"]`

HTML select/dropdown:

```
 <select (focus)="jobTitleList()">
   <option *ngFor="let jobTitle of jobList" value="">{{jobTitle}}</option>
 </select>
```

I am getting empty select box on my screen. Please help. I followed many posts but did not help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure, but check if it is because of the asynchronous call, I mean ur DOM is rendering before we get a response from getJobList() service.

Comment: Yes I think but I am unable to solve it. Could you please help.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Call ur function, jobTitleList() in ngOnInit() function. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
job: IJob;
jobList: IJob[];

jobTitleList() {
    this.getJobList().then(result => {
        this.jobList = result;
    });
}

<select [(ngModel)]="job" (focus)="jobTitleList()">
   <option *ngFor="let j of jobList" [value]="j">{{ j }}</option>
</select>
```